# Преобразование из css в scss

Tags: css, scss

Какая запись в scss будет эквивалента данной записи в css?

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
      color: #000;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$color_1: #000;

input[type=checkbox] {
    &:checked {
        &+label {
            &:before {
                color: $color_1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А в лоб - такая же. в scss допустим чистый css

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо!